# Failed to compile console program using external library

Tags: c++, dll, linker, lib, fmod

I am using windows 11 and using powershell 7.0 in windows terminal. I am trying to write a speed test program using neovim in the terminal, but I want to play sound in the program, so I installed the fmod library and #included it in the source code and used it. Then I ran the following command in the terminal to try to compile. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap6Fb.png)${g++} -g -I${headerDir} -L${LibraryDir} ${main.cpp} -o ${main.exe} -lfmod
However, an error stating that the definition of the method used in my source code could not be found appeared in all fmod-related method calls.
This is the current console program. I would appreciate it if you could let me know how this can be solved.

error sample:
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/137ad/OneDrive/Private/03. SourceCode/Code/selfCalc/selfCalc.cpp:83: undefined reference to `FMOD::System::playSound(FMOD::Sound*, FMOD::ChannelGroup*, bool, FMOD::Channel**)
...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap6Fb.png)

Comment: Don't use a OneDrive directory. Copy the lib in a local folder.

Comment: I'd guess you're using a visual studio build of fmod with gcc, that won't work